# Apk development code - <application android:name= "com.example.nameofapp.BaseApplication"> how is it included in the project or the libraries?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, apk

Good afternoon, I'm new to app development and I would like to see if there is someone who can give me like a tip or advice on this particular problem.

Basically this apk is going to use features from another apk and I think I understand how it's integrated inside the code, for example:

```
<application
        android:theme="@ref/0x7f14024a"
        android:label="@ref/0x7f13003b"
        android:icon="@ref/0x7f0f0000"
        android:name="com.example.appname.BaseApplication"

<activity
        android:name="com.example.appname.activities.SplashActivity"
        android:exported="true">
```

but my question is how do I include the actual app or anything necessary to use the features of this other app inside mine since it seems I have not included the app in the libraries or the project, but how do you achieve that? and "@ref/0x7f13003b" the part 0x7f13003b refers to a file in the libraries?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Explain what you actually want to do, your question isn't clear, and the code you pasted is just a compiled version of the manifest.

Comment: You're right, sorry, basically what I was wondering is how an app uses another app/or communicates to access data from another app, for example, these 3rd party apps on play store that require a video link from social media apps (facebook, youtube, etc) copied to the android device clipboard and automatically download the video. How do they achieve that? or if they actually use code from the original facebook app or if they use it as a provider.

Comment: Well, for that example you told us how they communicate-  you copied the link to the clipboard.  The clipboard can be read by any app.  So it acted on the data in there and downloaded it.  It doesn't need the app for that, that's just a download from the web.